# nhibernate : a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 2, of entity:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am getting the following error when i tried and save my "Company" entity in my mvc application

**a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 2, of entity:**

I am using an IOC container

```
private class EStoreDependencies : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {

            Bind<ICompanyRepository>().To<CompanyRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("session",
                                                                                       NHibernateHelper.OpenSession());
        }
    }
```

My CompanyRepository

```
public class CompanyRepository : ICompanyRepository
{
    private ISession _session;

    public CompanyRepository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }    

    public void Update(Company company)
    {

        using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            _session.Update(company);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

}

And Session Helper

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory; 
    const string SessionKey = "MySession";


    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                var configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.Configure();
                configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(UserProfile).Assembly);
                configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName,
                                          System.Environment.MachineName);
                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        //.GetCurrentSession()

        if (context != null && context.Items.Contains(SessionKey))
        {
            //Return already open ISession
            return (ISession)context.Items[SessionKey];
        }
        else
        {
            //Create new ISession and store in HttpContext
            var newSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            if (context != null)
                context.Items[SessionKey] = newSession;

            return newSession;
        }
    }
}
```

My MVC Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EStore.Domain.Model.Company company)
    {

            if (company.Id > 0)
            {

                _companyRepository.Update(company);
                _statusResponses.Add(StatusResponseHelper.Create(Constants
                    .RecordUpdated(), StatusResponseLookup.Success));
            }
            else
            {
                company.CreatedByUserId = currentUserId;
               _companyRepository.Add(company);
            }


        var viewModel = EditViewModel(company.Id, _statusResponses);
        return View("Edit", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a unit test?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I know this is a bit late and you might already found the solution, but maybe others could benefit from it...

This error is raised from nHibernate when you are updating an instance of an Entity that is saved on the Cache. Basically nHibernate stores your objects on the cache once you loaded it, so next calls would get it from the cache. If you update an instance that is present on the cache nHibernate throws this error otherwise it could cause dirty reads and conflicts regarding loading the old copy of the object. 
To get around this, you need to remove the object from the cache using the Evict method like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(EStore.Domain.Model.Company company) 
{ 

        if (company.Id > 0) 
        { 
            **ISession.Evict(company);**
            _companyRepository.Update(company);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying to this, Actually a badly drafted question by yours truly. Turns out that one of my entities was not using the same session which correlates to your explanation above.

Comment: That's a hack. I bet problem is that You don't flush and close previous session properly.

Comment: The issue appears to be that NHibernate doesn't recognize the newly created object (outside the NHibernate Session). See my answer.

Answer (score 14):

I tried @claitonlovatojr's hack, but I couldn't still handle the error.

All I had to do in my case wasy to replace my `ISession.Update(obj)` call to `ISession.Merge(obj)`.

In your repository, change:

```
public void Update(Company company)
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //_session.Update(company);
        _session.Merge(company); // <-- this
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Also, for more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171017/837726).

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution to this is to read the object from the database, copy the fields to the object, and save it. NHibernate session doesn't know anything about the incoming object which was instantiated by an MVC Model Binder.

In certain cases the whole object may not be visible or passed to the View/ViewModel. When saving it should first be read from NHibernate, then updated and saved.

```
Company cOrig = _companyRepository.Get(company.Id);
cOrig.PropertyToUpdate = company.PropertyToUpdate;
... // Copy the properties to be updated.
// Save the freshly retrieved object! 
// Not the new object coming from the View which NHibernate Session knows nothing about.
_companyRepository.Update(cOrig);
```

This requires parsing/mapping the ViewModel/Class properties to the Domain Model/Class, but in many cases you don't necessarily present them all to be updated in the view so you would need to do it anyway (Can't save partially empty objects on top of old objects).

Comment: This isn't always the correct way to fix this exception.  The problem hinges on what is stored in your current NHibernate session.  In my case, I was loading up an object for a system I was working on, but at some point I lost thread and also did what you did, and loaded up the same object, that I also tried to save on the same session.  NHibernate threw the error for the reason it said: the same object was on the session twice.  I fixed the problem by referring to the correct child item on the object that I originally loaded, and removed the repo call to load the item instance.

Answer (score 1):

for more agrgessive way you can use  the Clear() method

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this and Claiton Lovato's answer didn't work.  However Iko's did work. Here's a little more robust version of Iko's.  Downside is x2 trips to the db - one for the Get and another for the insert/update.

> A possible solution to this is to read the object from the database, copy the fields to the object, and save it.

```
public void Save(Company company)
{

    Company dbCompany = null;
    //update
    if (company.Id != 0)
    {
        dbCompany = _companyRepository.Get(company.Id);
        dbCompany.PropertyToUpdate = company.PropertyToUpdate;
    }
    //insert
    else
    {
        dbDefaultFreightTerm = company;
    }
    // Save either the brand new object as an insert
    // Or update the original dbCompany object with an update
    _companyRepository.SaveOrUpdate(company);
}
```

Comment: And so the fight against the ORM begins.