# One to Many mapping not Cascading deletes

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a simple model where a `Player` may choose a unique `Selection` of integers which are saved in a `Selection` table

Which looks like this

```
public class Player
{
    private readonly ICollection<Selection> selection;

    public Player()
    {
        this.selection = new List<Selection>();
    }

    public virtual long Id { get; set; }    
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Selection> Selection
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selection;
        }
    }

    public virtual void UpdateSelection(IEnumerable<int> balls)
    {
        this.selection.Clear();
        this.selection.AddRange(balls.Select(ball => new Selection { Player = this, Number = ball }));
    }
}

public class Selection
{
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I'm using to map the selection to the player

```
this.Bag(
    x => x.Selection,
    m =>
        {
            m.Key(k => k.Column("PlayerId"));
            m.Access(Accessor.Field);
            m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
            m.Inverse(true);
        },
    k => k.OneToMany());
```

And the selection map has a composed id

```
this.ComposedId(
    x =>
        {
            x.Property(y => y.Number);
            x.ManyToOne(y => y.Player, m => m.ForeignKey("PlayerId"));
        });
```

As I change this list using the `UpdateSelection` method of `Player` then the `Selection` table should insert and delete rows where necessary.

However, if I were to remove a number from the `Selection` when the Session.Update method is called I get the following error

```
Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'Could not execute command: INSERT INTO Selection (PlayerId, Number) VALUES (?p0, ?p1)
```

Which is self explanatory, but fixing it is not. Why is it trying to re-add the numbers, shouldn't it just delete the one I removed?

**Update**

I change the mapping from a Bag to a Set and now I don't get the duplicate key error. However it does not delete the number I removed from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your mapping of the Bag (now Set) you define

```
        m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        m.Inverse(true);
```

Defining both, Cascade and Inverse(true) would work against each other... Inverse(true) means that the other side should take care of updating changes, wich would negate the Cascade definition...

You should try to set Inverse(false) which would make the Bag responsible for the entity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ela, I updated the map as suggested and now I get the following error `NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`

Comment: I think its mainly because of how you do the UpdateSelection. You remove all current entries and then insert new ones. Thats not something I would do with nHibernate because nH does take care of all the object references and if you break it, you'll also have to remove those references. You can use session.evict to remove something, look also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983749/nhibernate-a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-assoc for another answer

Comment: The Evict didn't really yield any results. But I modified the UpdateSelection function so that only numbers which needed to be were removed. This seems to be working fine now