# Do I need to call SaveOrUpdate() after calling Merge()?

Tags: nhibernate, session

for reference I'm using version 2.1.2.4000 of Nhibernate.

I've spent pretty much an hour or so reading up the difference between Merge() and SaveOrUpdate() and no explanation attempts to just answer a really simple question??

I know that Merge() will do all the magic to synchronize the detached objects with cached or out of date instances.

BUT, once I've "merged", and I do not intend to change the entity any longer...

**Do I have to Still Call SaveOrUpdate?**

cheers

Comment: Have you tied both ways and observed the results?

Comment: it's a pretty straight forward question. do you know the answer?

Comment: No, but I was curious that you spent over an hour reading up to find the answer, when you could just discover it by trying.

Comment: cool an answer. next time someone had this issue they won't need to read ambiguous documentation nor jump over infrastructural hoops they might have just to find the intended clear behaviour of some methods. that's why SO's here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate). The point is that Merge() just puts together states from the session (from the database) and your detached object. You then should not use detached object any more but use newly returned object from the session that was merged. This object, of course, has to be "saved or updated" in order to persist changes because it has changed due to Merge operation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer here: [NHibernate - Difference between session.Merge and session.SaveOrUpdate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate)

Comment: that's quite an unhelpful answer. have you read either question fully? and have you read the other answer fully? take particular note of the second comment in the chosen answer.

Comment: Sorry, that was pretty clear to me, but Petr copied the same URL and gave you some details.

Comment: yep, the clarification and clarity was what I needed