# What is the usage of Session.Merge method in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session-management

What is the usage of Session.Merge method in NHibernate?

When can we use of this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NHibernate - Difference between session.Merge and session.SaveOrUpdate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try look here:

[NHibernate - Difference between session.Merge and session.SaveOrUpdate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/170962/735864)

from the above post:

> You should use Merge() if you are
>   trying to update objects that were at
>   one point detached from the session,
>   especially if there might be
>   persistent instances of those objects
>   currently associated with the session.
>   Otherwise, using SaveOrUpdate() in
>   that case would result in an
>   exception.