# nhibernate create with previous state

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, clone, interceptor

I have something similar to this

```
var productList = order.Products.TolIst();
```

And I loop through the productList and update each product using

```
session.SaveOrUpdate(product);
```

But the problem is, the previous state of the product in **OnFlushDirty** function is null (Which make sense).

Is there anyway to manage/ copy/ inject the previous state?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be related to detached objects updating. Try to read this very similar story: http://jamesfitzsimons.com/?p=152

Summary of the issue:

> ... On investigation we realised that the previousState parameter
>   passed into the onFlushDirty method of our interceptor was null. ...

The solution:

> The solution was to use the merge() method (new in NHibernate 2.0).
>   Merge() checks the first level cache to see if an object with the
>   given identifier has previously been loaded. If so it loads that
>   object out of the first level cache and updates it’s properties using
>   the detached object. This means that the session is now able to track
>   the changes made to the object so that when the flush occurs the
>   previousState is no longer null.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found this one also usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate

Comment: Yeah, stackoverflow and google search should be always the first option ;)