# What exactly does org.hibernate.Session.save() do?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know that `Session.save()` persists the transient object. And I see that it also has `saveOrUpdate()`, and also `persist()`.

I suppose then that `save()` is equivalent to `SQL INCLUDE`, is it?

If I have an object that already exists on DB and I `save()` it, will another row be included, will its fields be updated, or will it just be ignored and nothing happen?

Comment: Hi, did you check the Hibernate docs: http://www.hibernate.org/docs You don't mention which version you are using. Please use code blocks in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Difference between `save` and `saveOrUpdate`**

Main difference between `save` and `saveOrUpdate` method is that `save` generates a new identifier and `INSERT` record into database while `saveOrUpdate` can either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` based upon existence of record. So `save` will proceed without performing existence check, on the other hand `saveOrUpdate` will check for existence, if record exists it will be updated else a new record will be inserted.

**Basic differences between `persist` and `save`**

1. First difference between `save` and `persist` is their `return` type. Similar to `save` method, `persist` also `INSERT` records into database but return type of `persist` is `void` while return type of `save` is `Serializable object`.
2. Another difference between `persist` and `save` is that both methods make a transient instance persistent. However, `persist` method doesn't guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent instance immediately, the assignment might happen at flush time.

Comment: save() method can do an SQL update if the id was assigned manually (and it exists in the database)

Answer (score 6):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161224/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-saving-methods-in-hibernate):

> **save** Persists an entity. Will assign an identifier if one doesn't exist. If one does, it's essentially doing an update. Returns the generated ID of the entity.

I suggest you read the linked answer for further info.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it's happening like this:

1. `save()` is just saving your entity
2. `persist()` is modifying your instance as managed entity. this means that if you do an operation on it and your transaction is still open then it will be automatically saved when you call `flush()` (if I am not mistaken)
3. `merge()` there is also this one which is like `persist()` but it's returning a new instance and not modifying your old instance....
4. `saveOrUpdate()` you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate)

Answer (score 1):

save() method insert the record into database . but saveorupdate() method check the pk if pk is found then it's update the data else insert the data into database .