# Using one session per request, how to handle updating child objects

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, repository, webforms

I'm having some serious issues with Fluent Nhibernate in my ASP.NET WebForms app when trying to modify a child object and then saving the parent object.

My solution is currently made of 2 projects :

- Core : A class library where all entities & repositories classes are located
- Website : The ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms application

Here is my simple mapping for my Employee object:

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.DateCreated);
        Map(x => x.Username);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        HasMany(x => x.TimeEntries).Inverse().Cascade.All().KeyColumn("Employee_id");
    }
}
```

Here is my my mapping for the TimeEntry object:

```
public class TimeEntryMap : ClassMap<TimeEntry>
{
    public TimeEntryMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.DateCreated);
        Map(x => x.Date);
        Map(x => x.Length);
        References(x => x.Employee).Column("Employee_id").Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

As stated in the title, i'm using one session per request in my web app, using this code in Gobal.asax:

```
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = Core.SessionFactoryManager.CreateSessionFactory();

    public static ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get { return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"] = value; }
    }

    protected Global()
    {
        BeginRequest += delegate
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New Session");
            CurrentSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        };
        EndRequest += delegate
        {
            if (CurrentSession != null)
                CurrentSession.Dispose();
        };
    }
```

Also, here is my SessionFactoryManager class:

```
public class SessionFactoryManager
{
    public static ISession CurrentSession;

    public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Website.Properties.Settings.WebSiteConnString")))
        .Mappings(m => m
        .FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
        .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
        .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession GetSession()
    {
        return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"];
    }
}
```

Here is one of my repository class, the one i use to handle the Employee's object data operations:

```
public class EmployeeRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Employee
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public EmployeeRepository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        T result = null;
        using (ITransaction tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            result = _session.Get<T>(id);
            tx.Commit();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        IList<T> result = null;
        using (ITransaction tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            result = _session.Query<T>().ToList();
            tx.Commit();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public bool Save(T item)
    {
        var result = false;
        using (ITransaction tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
            tx.Commit();
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public bool Delete(T item)
    {
        var result = false;
        using (ITransaction tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _session.Delete(_session.Load(typeof (T), item.Id));
            tx.Commit();
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        var result = 0;
        using (ITransaction tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            result = _session.Query<T>().Count();
            tx.Commit();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, here is my problem.  When i'm trying to insert Employee(s), everything is fine.  Updating is also perfect... well, as long as i'm not updating one of the TimeEntry object referenced in the "TimeEntries" property of Employee...

Here is where an exception is raised (in a ASPX file of the web project):

```
            var emp = new Employee(1);
            foreach (var timeEntry in emp.TimeEntries)
            {
                timeEntry.Length += 1;
            }
            emp.Save();
```

Here is the exception that is raised:

> [NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier
>   value was already  associated with the session: 1, of entity:
>   Core.Entities.Employee]

Basically, whenever I try to

1. Load an employee and
2. Modify one of the saved `TimeEntry`, I get that exception.

FYI, I tried replacing the `SaveOrUpdate()` in the repository for `Merge()`.  It did an excellent job, but when creating an object using `Merge()`, my object never gets it's Id set.

I also tried creating and flushing the `ISession` in each function of my repository.  It made no sense because as soon as i was trying to load the `TimeEntries` property of an Employee, an exception was raised, saying the object could not be lazy-loaded as the ISession was closed...

I'm at lost and would appreciate some help. Any suggestion for my repository is also welcome, as i'm quite new to this.

Thanks you guys!

Comment: load the object first , then update it. You wont get that exception.

Comment: @DarthVader I modified my Employee repository to reflect what you suggested:

`public T GetById(int id)
        {
            T result = null;
            using (ITransaction tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //result = _session.Get<T>(id);
                result = _session.Load<T>(id);
                tx.Commit();
            }
            return result;
        }`

Unfortunately, the same error occurs.  Maybe I misunderstood your comment: are you suggesting that I load manually every object in the  List<TimeEntry> property?

Comment: Well, as the error says, you've already got a different object with the same ID value in the session. I'd be setting a breakpoint on the start of the request with a watch on `CurrentSession` to figure out where and when that "different object" is being set.

Comment: @Snixtor The object in the collection is modified in the last snippet of my question. I'd like to understand why I can't modify one of the children object, and then save the parent to propagate and commit all changes.  I thought that was what the `.Cascade.All()` attribute was meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
    var emp = new Employee(1);
    foreach (var timeEntry in emp.TimeEntries)
    {
        timeEntry.Length += 1;
    }
    emp.Save();
```

is creating a new Employee object, presumable with an ID of 1 passed through the constructor. You should be loading the Employee from the database, and your Employee object should not allow the ID to be set since you are using an identity column. Also, a new Employee would not have any TimeEntries and the error message clearly points to an Employee instance as the problem.

I'm not a fan of transactions inside repositories and I'm really not a fan of generic repositories. Why is your EmployeeRepository a generic? Shouldn't it be

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>
```

I think your code should look something like:

```
var repository = new EmployeeRepository(session);
var emp = repository.GetById(1);
foreach (var timeEntry in emp.TimeEntries)
{
    timeEntry.Length += 1;
}
repository.Save(emp);
```

Personally I prefer to work directly with the ISession:

```
using (var txn = _session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var emp = _session.Get<Employee>(1);
    foreach (var timeEntry in emp.TimeEntries)
    {
        timeEntry.Length += 1;
    }
    txn.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  By changing my repository implementation the way you suggested (calling the repo from the ASPX page), it works perfectly!
I guess my mistake was creating a new user by passing the id to the constructor (then the repo was called from within the object constructor and I was manualy copying all properties to the current object) and then expecting this object to be treated as the one coming from the repo... long story short: use the object returned by the repo!!!  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1):

This [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171017/314763) gives an excellent description of using merge.

### But...

I believe that you are facing issues with setting up a correct session pattern for your application.

I you suggest to take a look at **session-per-request** pattern 
where in you create a single NHibernate session object per request. the session is opened when the request is received and closed/flushed on generating a response.

Also make sure that instead of using `SessionFactory.OpenSession()` to get a session try using `SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()` which puts the onus on NHibernate to return you the current correct session.

I hope this pushes you in the right direction.