# NHibernate Insert With SubQuery

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, nhibernate, insert

I have a table structure of :

```
------------------------------------------------
|  id  |daily_index|monthly_index|   created   |
------------------------------------------------
| GUID |     1     |      1      |  10-12-2014 |
| GUID |     2     |      2      |  10-12-2014 |
| GUID |     1     |      3      |  11-12-2014 |
| GUID |     1     |      1      |  01-01-2015 |
------------------------------------------------
```

My goal is to have a transaction object with flexible natural code such as

> INV-{daily_index}/{month_in_roman}/{year_in_roman}/{monthly_index}

Or

> INV{ddmmyyyyhhiiss}-{monthly_index}-{daily_index}

Or whatever the user wishes it to be.

The class would have a `Code` property that will weave those private fields, for the sake of UI only.

In pure mysql query, I would do this:

`INSERT INTO transaction VALUES (// Some GUID, (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM transaction WHERE DATE(created) = DATE(NOW)), (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM transaction WHERE MONTH(created) = MONTH(NOW)), NOW());`

My question would be is there a way to reproduce this kind of INSERT mechanism in NHibernate?

I considered another option where I would to a SELECT query with COUNT query, but I don't know if that is possible with NHibernate.

Another option would be making a MySQL trigger, but I would love to know if this is possible to do directly in my project.

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate provides an option for overriding default insert statement: `sql-insert`:

Using this element in your mapping file, you can change the insert/update statements to your liking like this:

```
<class name="Student">
  <id name="Id" type="Int32">
    <generator class="assigned" />
  </id>
  <property name="Code" length="2000" />

  <many-to-one name="Class" column="ClassId" not-null="true"/>
  <sql-insert>insert into Student (Code, ClassId, Id) values (UPPER(?), ? , ?)</sql-insert>
</class>
```

Of course you'll have to customize `sql-update` also.

Determining the correct position for each column is tricky, though. This is from NH documentation:

> You can see the expected order by enabling debug logging for the
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity level. With this level enabled NHibernate
>   will print out the static SQL that is used to create, update, delete
>   etc. entities. (To see the expected sequence, remember to not include
>   your custom SQL in the mapping files as that will override the
>   NHibernate generated static sql.)

Reference:
[Custom SQL for create, update and delete](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-cud)

Answer (score 1):

Tha's what I like on NHibernate ... even here is a solution. What we would need is the:

#### [13.3. DML-style operations](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/batch.html#batch-direct)

Small cite:

> As already discussed, automatic and transparent object/relational mapping is concerned with the management of object state. This implies that the object state is available in memory, hence manipulating (using the SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) data directly in the database will not affect in-memory state. However, NHibernate provides methods for bulk SQL-style DML statement execution which are performed through the Hibernate Query Language (HQL).

About INSERT *(small extract)*:

> The pseudo-syntax for INSERT statements is: INSERT INTO EntityName properties_list select_statement. Some points to note:
>
> - **Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported; not the INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... form.**

- The properties_list is analogous to the column speficiation in the SQL INSERT statement. For entities involved in mapped inheritence, only properties directly defined on that given class-level can be used in the properties_list. Superclass properties are not allowed; and subclass properties do not make sense. In other words, INSERT statements are inherently non-polymorphic.
- ...

example from doc:

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

var hqlInsert = "insert into DelinquentAccount (id, name) " + 
                " select c.id, c.name from Customer c where ...";
int createdEntities = s.CreateQuery( hqlInsert )
        .ExecuteUpdate();
tx.Commit();
session.Close();
```

#### SOLUTION

having this we can create kind of this select:

```
var hqlSelect = 

// HQL select clause
" SELECT " +
// guid on the DB side
"  UUID(), " +
// this will return matches for today only
"  CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(created)=DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as int),"+
// this will return matches for this month - see WHERE
"  CAST(Count(*) as int)," +
// the time stamp into created
"   CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DateTime)" +

// From means - from some entity (the transaction here)
" FROM transaction" +

// Where is here restricting current month
// here we filter just this year and this month records
"   WHERE MONTH(created) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  " +
"     AND  YEAR(created) =  YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  ";
```

And this would be the COMPLETE insert

```
var hqlInsert = "INSERT INTO AuditLog (id, daily_index, monthly_index, created ) " 
              + hqlSelect; // the above select
```

And this should do what expected:

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

var hqlInsert = ... // see code above to create DML HQL
int createdEntities = session
     .CreateQuery( hqlInsert )
     .ExecuteUpdate();
tx.Commit();
session.Close();
```

Comment: Just a small note, but important comment. Any other solution - i.e. other then INSERT with SELECT - where all the stuff is computed on DB side - could lead to unexpected issues. Check this Q & A for some ideas what could happen if we use other kind of INSERT, i.e. we would **not** do it as described above: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20156729/1679310 (computed stuff in C# and issue with a bit later INSERT)