# class org.hibernate.TransactionException org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:100)

Tags: java, hibernate

my Application is gwt and hibernate below is my code

```
 public boolean changeUserStatus(long id, String status){
    try {
        Session session = HibernateFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        User user = (User ) session.get(User.class, id);
        user.setStatus(status);
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        transaction.commit(); 
        HibernateFactory.close(session);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
 }
```

**staktrace**

```
class org.hibernate.TransactionException
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:100)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1829.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489)
org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

see full stacktrace
When i try to  commit code it will give transaction Exception.
can anybody tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide a complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

try session.merge();

> saveOrUpdate() does the following:
>
> if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing if
> another object associated with the session has the same identifier,
> throw an exception if the object has no identifier property, save() it
> if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly
> instantiated object, save() it if the object is versioned (by a
>  or ), and the version property value is the same
> value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it otherwise
> update() the object
>
> and merge() is very different:
>
> if there is a persistent instance with the same identifier currently
> associated with the session, copy the state of the given object onto
> the persistent instance if there is no persistent instance currently
> associated with the session, try to load it from the database, or
> create a new persistent instance the persistent instance is returned
> the given instance does not become associated with the session, it
> remains detached

Here is the original answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/171017/3175948