# Hibernate merge creates copy of passed entity

Tags: java, hibernate

There is much information available on `merge` however I am confused as to why `merge` creates a copy of passed entity instead of persisting the passed entity itself?

Why is there a need of `merge` method? What is the use of calling `merge` method on new object?

Comment: why a copy is needed?

Comment: @Mat I just want to know why a copy is needed?

Comment: @jonskeet why the copy is needed?

Comment: See the answers of [NHibernate - Difference between session.Merge and session.SaveOrUpdate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate)

Comment: Please, post your effort to find an explanation yourself.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I checked various stackoverflow questions like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-hibernate . but there is no explanation why the copy is needed? everywhere it is mentioned that it creates a copy.